# UICollectionView showing wrong layer when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I know it's pretty common question. I've seen number of people ask here this type of a question, but I still can't seem to get it right.

I have a UICollectionView with pictures. I'm the getting the images from facebook so I'm using SDWebImage to load them.

Until here everything works ok.

The user can upload pictures that he took. so until the uploading process is finished and image was uploaded to facebook, I want the local image to be shown but with a layer (different alpha, activity etc') and once i get a notification from the server, the new image from facebook is replacing the local one.

My problem is that after adding the local images to the collectioView with the layer, more cells are displaying this layer and from time to time when i scroll up , the new images changes.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    PictureCell* cell = (PictureCell *)[_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[PictureCell reuseIdentifier] forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Picture *picture=(Picture *)[_campaign.pictures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    //If the picture is being uploaded, add the image from the local image property and set the blur layer

    if (!picture.facebookPicture) {
        cell.pictureImageView.image = picture.image;
    [cell TaggleBlur:YES];

    }
    else
    {
        [cell.pictureImageView sd_setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:picture.facebookPicture.source ]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"actionBar_pico_icon"]  completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
            NSArray *visibleIndexPaths = [_collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
            if (error==nil) {
                if ([visibleIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {

                    cell.pictureImageView.image = image;
                    [cell TaggleBlur:NO];

                }
            }
        }];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: set the imageview nil when it get added to cell content view.

Comment: I don't understand when to nil the imageView

Comment: I suggest for you to read a little bit about how UICollectionView reuses cells. When a collection view starts dequeueing a cell (collectionView:cellForItemAtItemPath: gets called), doesn't mean necessarily that your cell is visible. And if it's not, will won't set the image in cell.pictureImageView.image. If that happens, whatever image was being shown last time the cell was used is the image that will show up. Lastly, you should override prepareForReuse in PictureCell to both set the image to nil and also cancel any ongoing image download. I suggest to move the sd_setImageWithURL to the cell.

Comment: Basically you'd have two more method in PictureCell. 1. setPicture, which would be the facebook's source you're trying to set. There you would call sd_setImageWithURL:completed:. The other will be prepareForReuse, which will pretty much set the pictureImageView.image to nil and also (important) cancel the download for that imageView. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Last question. How can i cancel the download of the image to the imageView.
Thanks a lot!!!